# How to handle notably missing a tooth on the first day of a new job?

Tags: professionalism, new-job, retail

I'm starting a new position as a seasonal sales associate in retail, and my first day is tomorrow. Now, since I'm congenitally missing my right canine, I'm in the process of getting an implant, and while that's going on, I have a clear retainer with a false tooth to help disguise the very noticeable gap. However, I misplaced my case *somewhere* at home this weekend, and it's looking like I might not find it before I have to start tomorrow.

Since I'm almost certain I wouldn't have been offered this position without the illusion of a full set of teeth, what should I do? There's a whole new world of co-workers and customers to deal with, and I'm really not sure of what to do at this point.

Answer (score 12):

My advice to you...

**Walk tall.**  Go in, do your work, don't fret about your tooth.  It's a temporary situation.

It's very possible someone will ask you about it, especially if customer contact is important to your job.  If this does happen, just explain...  "Yeah, I'm missing a tooth.  Have a denture for it, but it's missing.  This will be resolved tomorrow."  [Substitute "tomorrow" with whatever time you can confidently either find or replace it]

Again, don't fret the small stuff.

Comment: +1 for this.
Its not a problem by default until you make it appear as one.

Comment: A great answer!!